# How to specify MDW username and password (user-level security) AND the database password (shared-level security) in an ODBC connection string?

Tags: ms-access, odbc, jet

I have an `.MDB` database for which a password (shared-level security) has been set.
The `.MDB` database also uses a corresponding `.MDW` workgroup database, to manage the respective username and password of every individual user (user-level-security).

For a user to successfully connect to the database, the workgroup file, username (user-level), password (user-level) and the database password (shared-level) need to be specified.

With **OLE DB**, this is pretty simple in a connection string:

- Workgroup file: `Jet OLEDB:System Database`
- Username (user-level): `User ID`
- Password (user-level): `Password`
- Database Password (shared-level): `Jet OLEDB:Database Password`

However, with **ODBC** it seems there is an option missing:

- Workgroup file: `SYSTEMDB`
- Username (user-level): `UID`
- Password (what level?): `PWD`

According to [SQLConfigDataSource (Access Driver)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/sqlconfigdatasource-access-driver?view=sql-server-ver15), the `PWD` option is the only password related one. However, the description just says `The password.`, without specifying which one, or how to use it.

So how can I specify both, user-level and shared-level passwords, in a single ODBC connection string `PWD` option?

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Normally, the use of PWD is inferred, but I doubt you can have a separate password for user-level security and global encryption using the ODBC driver. Note, though, that user-level security is easily broken, and has been deprecated and removed from ACE

Comment: @ErikA It would be unfortunate if this is another oversight by the Jet team, since it is working as it should be for OLE DB. However, if that is the case I would need to get my hands on the actual algorithm for determining when the `PWD` option is used for user-level and when for shared-level security. I'll try to contact the team. Regarding the fact that user level security isn't really security, I am aware of that. I am the lead developer of the `EntityFrameworkCore.Jet`, the Jet provider for EF Core, so we strive for as much backward compatibility as possible and need to support it anyway.